# Why do I have to precompile my assets in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, precompile

Lately I have to precompile my assets to see my css changes in my development environment. I don't know why this, the environment setting `config.assets.debug` is still set to true. I find this rather annoying, I believe I didn't have to run precompile after every change before. How do I make rails compile on page load again?

I'm running Rails 3.1.3. I don't know what other info to provide, please let me know what you need to know to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try completely removing your compiled assets and it should reset to the default development behavior. Otherwise, Rails will keep trying to load your precompiled `public/assets/` files before loading the stuff under `app/assets/`:

```
rake assets:clean
```

Comment: Very nice, I was looking for a good way to do this anyway, stupid I didn't run into it before.